# MDI children show the ContextMenu assigned to their MDI parent

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I'm creating an application, where the main form that is shown when the application is started is a MDI container. I assigned a context menu to this form, so that the user can use this menu to open MDI children.

This works just fine, but when I right click in a MDI child, the context menu of the MDI container (main form) opens, even though the child form does not have any context menu assigned, so I would expect (and want) no menu to open on right click.

How do I make sure that the children does not show the parent context menu?

As a side note I am working in VS2005, but I don't think this is relevant here.

I just can't seem to find the option / property to change this, and I would expect the default behaviour was the forms only show a context menu if one is assigned to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, setting the child form's ContextMenuStrip to null only makes it show the MDI parent's ContextMenuStrip.  The hack is to assign an empty ContextMenuStrip to the child form:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Form2 f2 = new Form2();
  f2.MdiParent = this;
  f2.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
  f2.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really expected the default behaviour of the children to just now show one as theirs are null. Just adding a new emtpy ContextMenuStrip to it, did indeed to the trick.